# How do I change <b> to <strong> in default richtext editor field

Tags: editor, html

How do I change  to  in default richtext editor field.   I have looked at the default HTML buttons - but this does not seem to update TextArea (rich text), but maybe (I haven't checked) updates TextArea.

How can I change  to  as  is deprecated.

The version we are using is ExpressionEngine Core Core v2.10.1 - Build Date: 20150501.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Note that the `b` tag is not "deprecated" - it still has meaning in HTML5, namely "stylistically offsetting text". [See more on this.](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/)

Answer (score 1):

Mate, you've got your work curt out!

I just spend a half hour of my time trawling through the compressed JS to find a solution, it's not coming easy!

The problem is the formatting seems to be applied via JS when your editing the field, this is courtisy of a plugin called Wysihat, but not just that, Wysihat has been modified to work with jQuery, then modified again to work with EE (closed source) and minified.

A much MUCH simplier solution would be to use a simple PHP snippet like so :

**_PHP On** parse on **output**

```
{exp:channel:entries ...}
  <?php
    //because PHP is on output, rte_text_field will be replaced 
    //with HTML before the PHP is evaluated
    $str = '{rte_text_field}';
    //now we simple do the old switch-er-oo, lets do i for em too!
    $needles = array('<b>','</b>','<i>',</i>');
    $replace = array('<strong>','</strong>','<em>','</em>');
    echo str_replace($needles, $replace, $str);
  ?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

There ya go, this took 5 minutes to write whereas decompiling and trying to work out what the heck is going on in the minified EE version of Wysihat will take an age. Heck just writing the previous senrtance took me longer than the snippet above!!!!